# There are too many errors for the IntelliSense engine to function properly, some of which may not be visible in the editor

Tags: c++, opencv

I am stuck with an error:

> There are too many errors for the IntelliSense engine to function properly, some of which may not be visible in the editor.

And a red line is shown in the first line before the first #include.

I was running my program by opencv in C++, and it was running correctly. I added a new item to solution files in order to test a new C++ code I needed, and then this error came up. As a result, I can do nothing. Trying previous answers to this question also did not help.

I removed all codes, and there only remains some include files and the error still exists. I also can see errors from ml.hpp file which was in my previous code and it is removed now. By removing #include for core.hpp, the error from core.hpp still exists. I even reinstalled visual studio to solve the problem and it did not work. I will appreciate if anybody can help?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "time:";
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you were getting?

Comment: those includes seem to be valid opencv includes, by your description, most probably is missing the opencv include directory in your project. You can add them in your project properties the C/C++ tab, General sub tab the first line that says "Additional Include Directories" should have the OpenCV include path

Comment: my error is "Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  There are too many errors for the IntelliSense engine to function properly, some of which may not be visible in the editor. installopencv c:\Users\M\Desktop\c++-p\c++\installopencv\installopencv\test.cpp 1 " and there can be seen a large number of errors below this. They are too long and i cannot post them.

Comment: I was running the code correctly, so it could not be include files. I also checked them.

Comment: some sample errors: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C2510 'Mat': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union installopencv d:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core.hpp 158 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error C3861 'imread': identifier not found installopencv d:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core.hpp 152 
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active)  expected a '}' test2 d:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\ml.hpp 1159

Comment: IntelliSense is at best an unreliable hint system. I personally switch it off, since it's annoying more often than it's helpful.

Comment: @molbdnilo You think?  I find it incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After spending two days on this issue, it was solved by downloading opencv folder and replacing that with the new one.